# printing an option value gives an un expected result?

Tags: angular

I am having an angular 5 project . I have a drop down box , which is populated by an array . I am chosing an option from the drop down and printing it . however i can see it is printing un expected values.

In my component class i have an inventories array

```
inventories: FlightInventory[] = [];
```

this is my model.ts where i define the FlightInventory

```
export enum FlightInventoryCode {
  SMS = 'SMS',
  MMS = 'MMS',
  EMAIL = 'EMAIL',
  MCN_VM = 'MCN_VM',
  PBE = 'PBE',
  PTU = 'PTU'
}

export enum FlightInventoryType {
  NUMBER = 'NUMBER'
}


export interface FlightInventory {
  id: string;
  label: string;
  code: FlightInventoryCode;
  type: FlightInventoryType;
  rate: number;
  isTagOn: boolean;
  allowSmsFallback: boolean;
}
```

in my template html

```
<select formControlName="inventory" [compareWith]="compareInventory" (change)="inventoryChanged($event.target.value);">
          <option value="" disabled>{{ 'PLACEHOLDERS.SELECT_INVENTORY' | translate }}</option>
          <option *ngFor="let inventory of inventories" [ngValue]="inventory">{{ inventory.label }}</option>
        </select>
```

in my component class i am trying to print the chosen option .

```
  inventoryChanged(event){
    console.log(event);
  }
```

currently i have only two items in my select box . so when i choose the items inventoryChanged is triggered . however the output is as follows.

```
1: Object
2: Object
```

however i would expect a FlightInventory object to be printed . any idea whats wrong here ?
appreciate any help

Comment: Try logging the form value `console.log(this.myForm.get('inventory').value)` instead ?

Comment: yes that works perfect ... thank you so much ....brilliant ...any idea why    console.log(event);
  } doesnt print ???

Comment: I don't know, it probably comes from the event itself, without a [mcve] I can't really tell you. I'm posting an answer so that you can close your issue !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comment, simply print the value of your form control :

```
console.log(this.myForm.get('inventory').value)
```

Answer (score 0):

console.log(JSON.stringify(event));